# Touch through UIImageView?

Tags: iphone, sdk, touch, imageview, behind

I have a transparent UIImageView with a button behind it. How can I touch "through" it and press the button underneath it?

Thanks

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Use `UIImageView.userInteractionEnabled = NO;`

That prevents it from receiving touches and all the touches will go through it.