# Manipulated Underlying Apps or Android OS

Tags: android

My initial question dealt with building a translucent view that allowed manipulation of a view below it.  Bluefalcon did an excellent job answering this and helped me understand view mechanics a little better:

[How can I interact with elements behind a translucent Android app?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app)

I'm still unsure of how to manipulate an underlying view that is not part of my app.  The effect I'm trying to achieve is like the Screen Filter App:

https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.haxor&hl=en

In this app, once started, it seems a "filter" view is placed on top of everything but you can still interact with whatever is running under it.  The app store, email, home screen etc.

I currently have getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCHABLE); in my app's onCreate method.  This seems to get close.  If I swipe on my app nothing updates, but when i back out of the app the home screen updates as if i swiped.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: "I'm still unsure of how to manipulate an underlying view that is not part of my app" -- that is because you can't, for obvious security and privacy reasons.

Comment: As mentioned in my question, the desired effect was achieved with the Screen Filter app, so there must be a way. But maybe not through use of views?