# Activity with specific height in front of lockscreen

Tags: android, android-layout, lockscreen, keyguard

I want to display an Activity in front of the Lockscreen. I tried with this code in my onCreate medthod:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Window window = getWindow();

window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);        
setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

That works great for Activities which are displayed over the whole screen but I want to build an Activity which is only 200px heigh. I thought I can match it with this code:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Window window = getWindow();

LayoutParams layout = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
layout.copyFrom(window.getAttributes());
layout.height = 200;

window.setAttributes(layout);
window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);

setContentView(R.layout.test);
```

But then the Activity is not visible in front of the lockscreen. If I unlock the phone the Activity is displayed directly. Any ideas why and how I can fix this?

**EDIT:** I think it has something to do with the window floating FLAG. If this flag is set (and I think it will when I change the size) the activity is not displayed over the lockscreen. But this is only a presumption. Any ideas or a workaround to fix this?

Comment: Are you expecting to see the `Lockscreen`(partially) behind the activity?

Comment: Yes that is the problem. I want to see the lockscreen behind the activity and may want to unlock the phone while the activity is over the lockscreen (if that is possible)

Comment: I hope someone can help you out. But, most likely, this will not work.

Comment: I found a workaround this (even though it's not tested yet): `KeyguardManager  myKeyGuard = (KeyguardManager)getSystemService(Context.KEYGUARD_SERVICE);
myLock = myKeyGuard.newKeyguardLock("tagName");
myLock.disableKeyguard(); ` - with the permission in the Manifest `android.permission.DISABLE_KEYGUARD`. Then alternatively try `Window window = getWindow();
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);
window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON);`.

Comment: Thanks for your help but that is not want I want. The first solution disabled the lockscreen completly. The second shows the ativity after I unlocked the phone but not in front of the lockscreen. I really want to see the lockscreen behind the activity and may want to unlock the phone while the activity is over the lockscreen (if that is possible)

Comment: have u implemented getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED); ???

Comment: Yes I have that's the code from line 4

Comment: I have the exact requirement. And I'm facing the same problems that you have faced. Did you find any answer?

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar requirement while designing my music player. What I finally end up doing for my lock screen widget is:

1. Had a transperent background for my Lock screen widget.
2. added a button "Click to exit to lockscreen" at the bottom of layout.
3. To give a feel of box, added a white boundary around the buttons.

You can have a look at it by downloading my musicplayer "Fusion Music Player" from Google Play

Answer (score 0):

First of all save to preferences `Keyguard` instanse.

After that - disable programmatically default lockscreen on your phone.

Then, implements `Service` which catch when phone go to lock state.

When `SCREEN_ON` check Activity in stack, if she exist show her, NO  - launch by `singleTask`.

It's a single way to implementing Activity on Lockscreen. Because Google reject make-up lockscreens and any manipulating with this things are hack's.

You can make widget and put him to lockscreen or below writing way.

FYI: google it **my lock for android** (Source on code.google.com)

Answer (score 0):

Finally I achieved the same. Don't go for activity, because android will not show lock screen behind your activity for security reason, so for service.

Below is my code **in onStartCommand of my service**

```
WindowManager mWindowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

View mView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.score, null);

WindowManager.LayoutParams mLayoutParams = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0, 0,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DISMISS_KEYGUARD
                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_TURN_SCREEN_ON
        /* | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON */,
        PixelFormat.RGBA_8888);

mWindowManager.addView(mView, mLayoutParams);
```

Answer (score -1):

Your best bet will be to create a `View` that fills the screen, but has a *transparent* background everywhere other than the part that you want.

This can be done by defining a custom theme in the file `res/values/styles.xml` (originally shown on [How do I create a transparent Activity on Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2176922/how-to-create-transparent-activity-in-android)):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <style name="Theme.Transparent" parent="android:Theme">
    <item name="android:windowIsTranslucent">true</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/transparent</item>
    <item name="android:windowContentOverlay">@null</item>
    <item name="android:windowNoTitle">true</item>
    <item name="android:backgroundDimEnabled">false</item>
  </style>
</resources>
```

Then adding this theme to your `Activity`'s Manifest declaration:

```
android:theme="@style/Theme.Transparent"
```

Next, you can create the layout (`R.layout.lockscreen`) for this Activity by adding this `XML` file. Here you specify the height in pixels:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <FrameLayout 
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="200px"
        android:centerInParent="true" >

        <include layout="@layout/test" /> <!-- This points to your R.layout.test layout. -->

    </FrameLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Finally, just use the first method shown above to show the Activity:

```
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
Window window = getWindow();

window.addFlags(LayoutParams.FLAG_SHOW_WHEN_LOCKED);        
setContentView(R.layout.lockscreen);
```

Comment: But with this method it is not possible to unlock the screen while the activity is visible. Or can I create something to click throught the activity?

Comment: @Cilenco I have not dealt much with `Window`s, and do not know for sure. The same question was asked [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app), and has an answer that may work. Also, check out the flags listed [here](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/WindowManager.LayoutParams.html), which may change how the window is inserted (above or below soft input, etc).

Comment: @Cilenco please tell me, did this solution worked, because i tired this, and even in this case(fix height), lockscreen not getting displayed behind it, rather launcher screen gets displayed behind my activity