# Android Create "Ghost" Image (Touch-through)

Tags: android, image, overlay

I have created a `service` which will overlay an image on top of the whole screen.

This part is the code which will overlay an image on top of the whole screen:

```
@Override public void onCreate() {
    super.onCreate();

    windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

    img = new ImageView(this);
    img.setImageResource(R.drawable.image); // Image is .png format

    WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
        WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
        PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.CENTER | Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        windowManager.addView(img, params);
}
```

However, any space which the image covers in untouchable. I want the image to be just overlaid, without affecting any other components on the screen, similar to what this does:

[image: CPU usage overlay example]

How can I make the area beneath the image touchable (touch-through)?

**Edit**
It seems that the transparent space of the image fills a square, and covers the screen (FYI).
So my ultimate goal is, to make the image **touch-through**.

I have tried the `popupWindow` class, recommended by a few SO users, but its purpose does not fulfill my needs and does not work.

Comment: You can use a RelativeLayout below ImageView with background color like that #99000000, important part "#99" to Alpha color or use transparent color and add onClick events to RelativeLayout

Comment: Does it work if you add `return false` in onTouchListener of an imageview, so touch event can be passed to relative layout instead?

Comment: Setting `return false`on onTouchListener didn't work. It seems that the image is causing the problem: the blank space. Is there a way to remove the blank space?

Comment: NO. The "blank" space... just **isn't blank**. Instead, it is **transparent** (that is, it is filled with "see-through" pixels, which arent "touch-through" - they are a solid barrier covering the screen, like a **glass sheet**).

Comment: So how to make every pixel touch through?

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "Service", in Android that has a special meaning.

Comment: As a caution, you've made a lot of seemingly trivial edits to "bump" this question. Please stick to making more substantial edits, as frequent edits like this can be seen as exploiting the system.

Comment: Actually service is correct since it will be used to display above the entire screen, even when the app is closed.

Comment: You could add a touch listener to the overlay, manually intercept touch events, examine the coordinates that were touched, and re-route the touch event to the underlying views accordingly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11635934/touch-through-translucent-app

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found that `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY` solves the issue.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
img.setClickable(false);
```

[http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable(boolean)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#setClickable%28boolean%29)

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the param flags to:

```
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL | 
WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
```

I've tried this with success before.  The last two will help send touch events to the views behind it.